# Different powers of a primitive root simultaneously lying in a subspace

Tags: finite-fields, finite-geometry

Let $p$ be a large prime and let $\alpha$ be a root of a primitive quadratic polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Let $N$ be an integer parameter of size proportional to $p$ and $$V = \{\alpha + b : b \in \mathbb{F}_p\} \subset \mathbb{F}_p(\alpha).$$ Set  $$S=\{(a , b , c) \in [N]^3 , y \in \mathbb{F}_p(\alpha) : \alpha^a , \alpha^b , \alpha^c \in y \cdot V , \ \  a < b < c\},$$ where $[N] = \{1 , \ldots , N\}$.  Do we have estimates for $\#S$?

With 3-tuples replaced by 2-tuples or 1-tuples, we have the asymptotics $\sim N^2 /2$ and $\sim pN$, respectively.